# Adjusting custom Tableviewcell - NSLayoutConstraint conflict. UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am having a problem with autolayout Programmatically.I am adjusting a tableviewCell with a custom UIView.The uiView have an image inside with no issues.I am getting this error.What am doing wrong here?

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034e0e10 V:|-(1)-[XKCD_Comics.CardView:0x7f932b610f80]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f932b6085c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034e1a90 XKCD_Comics.CardView:0x7f932b610f80.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f932b6085c0.bottom - 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034e2120 XKCD_Comics.CardView:0x7f932b610f80.height == 310   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034e1590 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f932b6085c0.height == 312.5   (active)>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034e2120 XKCD_Comics.CardView:0x7f932b610f80.height == 310   (active)>
```

Contstraints

```
func createViewHierarchy() {
        //Initialize constaints Array
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        
        //Setting up constraint for UIVIEW - ComicsView
        constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10))
        constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10))
        constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10))
        constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10))
        constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 310))

        //activate NSLayoutconstaints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views can end up with non-whole-number heights due to the way cell separators are rendered.

So, on a device with `@2x` screen scale, your  `comicsUIVIew` height will end up at `310.5` ... on a `@3x` device, it will be `310.333`

If that's acceptable, you can avoid the auto-layout complaints by changing the Priority on your height constraint:

```
    //constraints.append(comicsUIVIew.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 310))

    let hc = comicsUIVIew.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 310)
    hc.priority = .defaultHigh
    constraints.append(hc)
```

If you need `comicsUIVIew` to be ***exactly*** `310` points, you can add a clear "spacer" view (or a `UILayoutGuide`) below `comicsUIVIew`, giving it a height constraint of 0.0 with priority of `.defaultHigh`. It will end up being `0.5` or `0.333` points tall.

Or... set `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`, and design your cell to have a "bottom border line" to simulate the separator if desired.